# CSS keyframe animation with multiple properties

Tags: css, css-animations, cakeyframeanimation

I have a container div with an object inside of it. I can animate one property of it, e.g. bottom, OR left, but can't animate BOTH at the same time.
How does one animate both properties at the same time so it moves diagonally? I don't understand why the following code does not work:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}

@keyframes move { 
    0%     { left:   0px; bottom:   0px; }
    100%   { left: 122px; bottom: 157px; }
}

#object {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px; 
    left:   0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    /*animation: name duration timing-function delay iteration-count direction fill-mode play-state; */    
    animation: move 2.5s linear 0s infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *does*  move diagonally:

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    height: 180px;
}

@keyframes move { 
    0%     { left:   0px; bottom:   0px; }
    100%   { left: 122px; bottom: 157px; }
}

#object {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px; 
    left:   0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    animation: move 2.5s linear 0s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"><div id="object">MOVING</div></div>
```

Comment: It does look a little zigzag-y in Firefox :-D

Comment: Ah flip you are right, thank you! This is my first animation. I kept googling and could not find multiple properties animation examples. After 1 hour of staring at not much code, I copied paste one thing at a time until it broke... turns out I had two nested calc's , and only one closing bracket. Still getting used to no compiler warnings.

Comment: @run_the_race what was the issue? I don't see any difference between the answer and question code

Comment: The difference was I took a snippet of the code, and simplified it for posting here, and by simplifying it, it removed the bug. I was also under the wrong impression one could not animate 2 properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider translation to have the same movement with better performance:

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    height: 180px;
}

@keyframes move { 
    0%     { transform:translate(0,0) }
    100%   { transform:translate(125px,-125px) }
}

#object {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px; 
    left:   0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    animation: move 2.5s linear 0s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"><div id="object">MOVING</div></div>
```